# Regex matching "dem" but not "democrat" in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to match a certain substring ("dem") but do not want to match on a specific string that includes that substring ("democrat"). Can this be done using grep?

For example, I have the following:

```
> my_text <- c("demRace", "democrat", "demGender")
> grepl(pattern = "dem", x = my_text)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

And my desired output is:

```
> grepl(pattern = some_pattern, x = my_text)
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: May be `grepl("dem", my_text)&!grepl("democrat", my_text)`

Comment: Or `grepl(pattern = "dem(?!ocrat)", x = my_text, perl = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses a negative lookahead:

```r
my_text <- c("demRace", "democrat", "demGender")
grepl(pattern = "dem(?!ocrat$).*", my_text, perl=TRUE)

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `.*$` is redundant. `grepl` does not require a full string match.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
my_text <- c("demRace", "democrat", "demGender")
my_text <- my_text[!grepl(pattern = "democrat", x = my_text)]
grepl(pattern = "dem", x = my_text)
```

**EDITED (to fix the issues pointed out below by Onyambu)**

```
my_text <- c("demRace", "democrat", "demGender") -> tmp
tmp[grepl(pattern = "democrat", x = tmp)] <- "x"
grepl(pattern = "dem", x = tmp)
```

Comment: Remember one should get FALSE for democrat. This removes democrat. so its incorrect

Comment: Thanks, @Onyambu. Good point! However, if the goal of the OP is to collect the matched words, my code works.

Comment: Look at the desired results. Then you will not that this code doesn't anser the question

Comment: My edited code now produces the FALSE you mentioned, @Onyambu. Thanks!

Comment: That changes the original text. You are not supposed to do that.

Comment: We can use a temporary variable, @Onyambu! Edited accordingly.